# PHP: Form stops to pass the data after a user has logged in

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I want to sort the items on the page and for that I am using this form:

```
<form method="get" action="">
            <label for="sort">Sort items by</label>
            <select id="sort" name="sort">
                <option value="">-</option>
                <option value="plth">Price (Low to high)</option>
                <option value="phtl">Price (High to low)</option>
                <option value="naz">Name (A-Z)</option>
                <option value="nza">Name (Z-A)</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="sortSubmit" value="GO >">
        </form>
```

After the form has been processed, I will use some sql statements to retrieve the items in desired order from database:

```
if(isset($_GET["sortSubmit"]) && $_GET["sort"] == "plth") {
                    $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY PRICE ASC";
                }
                elseif (isset($_GET["sortSubmit"]) && $_GET["sort"] == "phtl") {
                    $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY PRICE DESC";
                }
                elseif (isset($_GET["sortSubmit"]) && $_GET["sort"] == "naz") {
                    $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY NAME ASC";
                }
                elseif (isset($_GET["sortSubmit"]) && $_GET["sort"] == "nza") {
                    $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY NAME DESC";
                }
```

The problem is, everything is working fine until a user logs in. After the user has logged in, the ordering of the items stops working completely and I cannot figure out why. With some testing echo statements I found out the form is not passing any data anymore. When a user logs out, the ordering works fine again. I cant imagine how passing the data from a form has to do something with sessions or cookies.
Thanks for any ideas.

EDIT:
This is my login part:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include("includes/constants.php");
include("includes/config.php");
if(isset($_POST['accountLogin'])) {
    $query_login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = ' ".$_POST['accountPass']." ' and email = ' ".$_POST['accountEmail']." ' ";
    $sql_login = mysqli_query($connection, $query_login);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_login) > 0) {
        $login_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_login);
        //echo $login_data['firstName'] . $login_data['lastName'];
        //echo $login_data['email'];
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $login_data['ID'];
        $_SESSION['userEMAIL'] = $login_data['email'];
        $_SESSION['userNAME'] = $login_data['firstName'].$login_data['lastName'];
        setcookie('userID', $login_data['ID'], time() + (60 * 60 * 60 * 3));
        setcookie('userEMAIL', $login_data['email'], time() + (60 * 60 * 60 * 3));
    }
    else {
        echo '<div id="wrongHidden" style="text-align:center;width:200px;height:300px;position:fixed;top:53px;right:4.4%;background:#dedede;color:red;border:1px solid black;z-index:55;    border-radius:5px;padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;font-size:20px;">Incorrect password or email!<br><br><button type="button" class="btn" style="border:1px solid black;position:absolute;bottom:5px;left:15px;width:190px;" onclick="hideBtn()">OK</button></div>';
    }
}
```

EDIT2: 
Code that is being executed first in the page with the form:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
include("header.php");
include("includes/config.php"); 
//ADDING THE PRODUCTS TO THE CART:
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "add") {
    if(isset($_GET['pid'])) {
        $pid = intval($_GET['pid']); 
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$pid])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$pid]['quantity']++;
        }
        else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = ($pid)";
            $do_query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($do_query) > 0) {
                $product_row = mysqli_fetch_array($do_query);
                $_SESSION['cart'][$product_row['ID']] = array("quantity" => 1, "price" => $product_row['PRICE']);
            }
            else {
                echo 'Invalid product!';
            }
        }
    }   
}
// END OF ADDING THE PRODUCTS TO THE CART
?>
```

Comment: If this code works, problem is elsewhere HTML and these SQL queries has nothing to do with logged user. Show how you log the user in. What means 'stops working'? Any error? Blank page? ...?

Comment: I meant the ordering of the items stops working since the form is not passing any data anymore after the user has logged in.

Comment: show us the code how you make user log in to your application.

Comment: Just edited the question :)

Comment: Can you post more of the page that contains the processing part (from the top of page that contains `if(isset($_GET["sortSubmit"]) && $_GET["sort"] == "plth") etc..`)?

Comment: Just edited the question. But it contains only the part for adding products to the cart which I believe has nothing to do with this.